# Docker run getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While trying to run a spring boot application inside the Docker getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /opt/java/openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.so" error.

DockerFile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Below is the full stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /opt/java/openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:285)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2403)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1388)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1423)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported(Desktop.java:329)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:303)
    at com.docusign.App.openHomePage(App.java:65)
    at com.docusign.App.main(App.java:37)
    ... 8 more
```

I am not sure what to do, appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Are you able to run the jar file locally using `java -jar app.jar` ? I tested your docker script with a hello world jar file and it seems to be working as expected so I think the issue could be coming from the logic in java code rather than docker. It would be great if you can share the java code that compiles the jar file

Comment: The backtrace and library name suggest you're trying to run an interactive desktop GUI application of some sort, and this tends to not work well in Docker.  [Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to open allure-reports in webdriver.io project](/q/67391845) suggests a "headless" JRE could be the root problem, though you can't change the JRE in the image; [Running Java Swing GUI application on Docker](/q/55708634) hints a non-Alpine image might work better.